# call artisan command using shell script

Tags: php, laravel

can we call artisan command using PHP exec or shell_exec or system function?

```
exec('php artisan list');
```

I have tried the above command in the controller but it is giving me an error saying
'Could not open input file: artisan'
actually, I want to call another artisan command this just for testing

please guide me if am doing anything wrong here

Comment: seems to be something related to your php file permissions. If it's on a dev server, try chmod it to 777 to test.

Comment: ok, let me check

Comment: In a controller you say? The artisan file is located in the root folder of the project, meaning that you would need to use the relative path or the absolute path in order to reach the artisan file :)

Comment: good point zeppo, but I think that would say file not found. "Could not" to me seems like a permission issue. Can't test it as I dont have an environment handy right now.

Comment: True Oliver... I tried using exec('php artisan'); in one of my project and got the error "Could not open input file: artisan". However, when I used the absolute path, it worked fine. @sayyedtabrez, any progress?

Comment: yes, thank you @Zeppo and @Oliver, this command is working fine `exec('php /var/www/html/artisan list')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The artisan file is located in the root folder of the project and you are trying to execute it from a controller in a different folder. Try using the absolute path or a relative path:

```
exec('php /path/to/rootfolder/artisan list');
```